# Making nested table in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, nested, schema

I have a JSON dataset and it is in array format. I have to make a table in Postgres-SQL and then store the data into it. I haven't ever worked with this complex data. I am trying to figure out which column belongs from which values. how can I make a nested table in PostgreSQL and load data into it?

I searched about this and came to Postgres SQL does not support nested tables by some websites.

[image]

Comment: Is your structure always the same, or are you storing dynamic hierarchical data?

Comment: What is your definition of a nested table? Data normalization is nothing new, and should/could be applied here as well. Start with a 3NF model and most likely you will stick with that one just because it works

Comment: I am familiar with normalization forms but the reason is, according to my research I visited many websites to solve this error and most of the time the answer is similar that postgresql does not support nested table, and though its my first project with postgresql and don't have much knowledge about this so that's why I am stuck here

Comment: PostgreSQL supports normalized, data, supports arrays and supports json/jsonb. What is it that is doesn't support? And what problem are you tying to solve? Without being rude, but there is nothing in the data or data structure that you showed us, that can't be stored in a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

While PostgreSQL doesn't have a native "nested table" construct like some other databases, you can effectively work with hierarchical or nested data using JSON or JSONB data types. The choice between JSON and JSONB depends on whether you need to preserve the original JSON structure (use JSON) or if you want to store it in a more efficient binary format (use JSONB).The benefits using json or jsonb are:

- Much quicker to process, and it enables indexing, which might be a big
  advantage.
- substituting entity-attribute-value (EAV) tables with jsonb columns, which
  can be queried, indexed, and joined resulting in speed increases.

**NB:** if your data  contains graph-related relationships, you can use Apache AGE, it allows you to work with graph-related relationships within PostgreSQL's relational model by providing a graph database extension. By modeling your data using tables and leveraging AGE's graph query capabilities, you can effectively manage and query graph data in PostgreSQL. Be sure to refer to the Apache AGE documentation for more details on its specific features and query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use jsonb on postgres. Something along the lines -

```sql
CREATE TABLE awayTeam (
    data jsonb
);
```

What you'd need to do is make a `.json` file that is of the structure that you mentioned in the image and then, create this table with a `jsonb` object in it. You should then load that `.json` file onto the table using

```sql
COPY awayTeam(data) FROM '/path/to/data.json';
```

for querying, you can do

```sql
SELECT data->>'name' FROM awayTeam;
```

or, in case of nesting

```sql
SELECT data->'address'->>'city' FROM awayTeam;
```

You can easily query and manipulate nested JSON structures using the `->` and `->>` operators.